# Location Not Set Exception when launching JavaFX program

Tags: java, javafx

I documented the issue at my GitHub repo for this project: https://github.com/Sheepzez/Matrixonator-Java/issues/3

The main problem seems to be the lines:

```
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

This code worked before, but when I started the app up I got the error you can see at the GitHub Issue. It seems like view/RootLayout.fxml is no longer the location of RootLayout.fxml, but I made no changes to this so I'm not sure why it decided to not like it.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Edit: All the code is also visible on that GitHub repo.

Comment: I've tested your project, it's working for me. You can try this to avoid possible relative path problems: `loader.setLocation(MatrixOverviewController.class.getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));`

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks, using that line fixed the issue! Must have been some of relative path problem.